# Invalid Customer ID - google-ads-api, I have provided correct customer_id set but it is returning error

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-ads-api, adsense

I am using `google-ads-api` module in nodejs to connect with Google Ads API.

I am using this code block to get `Customer`

```js
const customer = client.Customer({
    customer_id: 'XXX-XXX-XXXX',
    refresh_token: refreshToken,
})
```

I have used `XXX-XXX-XXXX`, `XXXXXXXXXX`, `XXXX-XXX-XXX` format for `customer_id` but still it is returning this error

```sh
GoogleAdsFailure {
  errors: [
    GoogleAdsError {
      error_code: [ErrorCode],
      message: "Invalid customer ID ''."
    }
  ],
  request_id: 'OcUdfalh_N0U4hTJUd6c6g'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

from https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/best-practices/common-errors#client_customer_id_invalid

i think you should remove the "-" from customer id

Answer (score 0):

if it's through an `environment variable` in and IDE like `pycharm` got to `Run > Edit Configurations > Enviroment variables` use the format XXXXXXXXXX. Also make sure that the customer id is related to an ads manager account in that case use it's customer id and if it's a regular ads account use it's own customer id.